# Multiple Apps vs Single App with A lot of Activity for SuperApps

Tags: android

I have a specific question about the challenges of managing and scaling a large Android project, which is sizable and still expanding. Using Multiple Apps with Shared Components, multiple apps can communicate with each other through Intents and possibly employ a unique authorization method.

This inquiry is essentially an assertion based on my current understanding, and I'd like to confirm if my assumptions are accurate or if there are aspects I might have overlooked.

- Single App with Multiple Activities:

  - Advantages:

    - **Code Centralization**: All code is in one place, which can simplify navigation and dependency management.
    - **Consistent UI/UX**: Easier to maintain a consistent user interface and user experience across the entire application.
  - Challenges:

    - **Build and CI Time**: Larger codebases can lead to longer build and CI times, impacting development speed.
    - Development requires substantial computing resources (CPU & Memory), even for minor changes.
    - Continuous Integration (CI) builds may be time-consuming, contingent on various factors.
    - **Complexity**: Over time, the codebase may become complex and harder to manage, especially for new developers joining the team.
    - The codebase's manageability depends on adherence to company standards; effective compliance facilitates management, while non-compliance poses significant challenges.
- Multiple Apps with Shared Components:

  - Advantages:

    - **Modularity**: Each app can be developed and maintained independently, leading to better modularity.
    - **Smaller Codebase**: Development requires lower resources when creating individual apps.CI processes could be parallelized between each app.
    - **Parallel Development**: Different teams or developers can work on different apps simultaneously, potentially speeding up development.
  - Challenges:

    - **Code Duplication**: While shared components can reduce redundancy, there might still be some level of code duplication or the need to synchronize changes across multiple repositories.
    - **Consistency Challenges**: Ensuring a consistent user interface and experience across multiple apps might require extra effort.
  - Additional Considerations:

    - **Testing Complexity**: Testing scenarios involving multiple apps can be more complex than testing a single app. Coordinating end-to-end testing across multiple apps may require additional effort.

Considering the benefits and trade-offs of having multiple apps, it's relatively uncommon in some startup circles, including mine in Southeast Asia. I'm curious if there are unknown trade-offs associated with this approach that I might not be aware of.

Thank you !